# CSR for iPage site with Third Party SSL

Tags: security, ssl, hosting, csr, namecheap

after recently setting up a website on iPage I have come across an issue not listen on their website. **You cannot get a CSR code from them**, and so you cannot easily use a Third Partly SSL. So I am simply wondering how I could generate my own CSR code that will work with a site hosted on iPage.

**Any help is greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

Well CSR stands for certificate signing request. It is code that is used to generate a SSL certificate. You can generate the CSR code using openssl command. See this link for more information: https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-apache.htm.

You can also generate a CSR using an online service such as: https://csrgenerator.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your csr using [csr.ninja](http://csr.ninja). It's easy and will send you a copy by mail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in shared hosting, third party SSL will not work. You will have to install their own provided SSL certificates. Their VPS and Dedicated hosting platform supports third party SSL installation